# I am confused with maven dependencies: "org.eclipse.persistence.jpa" and "org.hibernate"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

I have a Spring MVC project using Maven.
I am using Spring-data-jpa as one of my dependency:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Spring-data-jpa provides the api.
Therefore, I need to add another dependency which implements jpa. However, I am confused about:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

What is eclipse.persistence? And the difference with hibernate? 
Please help!

Comment: (unrelated to your question) PDFBox is at 2.0.5.

Comment: spring-data-jpa doesn't provide the API. It is a wrapper which makes us write the queries in a easy and concise way. jpa is the API specification. Hibernate is one of the implementations of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse Persistence (EclipseLink) and Hibernate are both implementations of Java Persistence API, each with their own extra features and often their own bugs. In terms of speed, they're very similar to each-other, compared to the other implementations.

Only one of is used in each persistence unit, defined in `META-INF/persistence.xml`. Look at yours, inside the `persistence-unit`->`provider` node you will find the class that is used.
If it starts with `org.hibernate`, then you can safely remove the eclipse dependency.
If it starts with `org.eclipse`, you can remove the hibernate dependency.
If you have multiple persistence units, each one can use a different implementation/provider.

Comment: Yes, they are very similar, but eclipselink is more light weighted.